# Why does OAuth use HTTP GET to return the access token?

Tags: http, oauth, rfc

In the OAuth authentication flow, if permission is granted by the service provider, the authorization redirects to a app-specified redirect URL with the access token (e.g. `yourapp.com/redirect/?token=deadbeef`).

Now the app has to store that token in some way – either directly store it in the database or start a session with the service provider. Doesn't this contradict the "laws" of HTTP methods, specifically that GET is supposed to be a read-only action?

Comment: You can’t use anything else than GET in redirects and the rule that nothing should be edited, created or deleted is usually for some data or items. Logging in is state, which is a bit different. Usually logging out is also GET

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen most modern/security aware web frameworks use delete or post for logout

Comment: Yet to see a single site that doesn’t have a logout link as a normal link with GET, but may be a case of YMMV